# Dropdownlist and Entity objects

Tags: asp.net, entity

I'm using Entity Framework and I want to bind a list of one of them to a dropdownlist. This is working well. But there's just one problem. What is the best practice to go to an outter object linked to the entity listed?

I.E: A command which have ID, date, refCandidatID, etc. and for some reason, on my dropdownlist, i want to show the firstname of my candidat

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCommand" runat="server" DataTextField="Candidat.FirstName" DataValueField="ID" AppendDataBoundItems="true" />
```

What should i do cuz it keeps throwing me an error when binding the Dropdownlist.

*Note : Sorry for my english.*

Comment: DataBinding: 'Context.PocoProxies.CommandeProxy' does not contain a property with the name 'Candidat.FirstName'. But it realy exists, and the property its loaded when I go in it in debuggin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I saw is to make another object such as "MyListItem" and my facade return a list of MyListItem previously feeded with ValueField = CommandID and TextField = Candidat.FirstName. Is there any other solution?